# E0210 (Uncovered Type Parameter) when implementing `From<LocalType<ExternalType>> for ExternalType`

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, traits

I'm working with the `rp2040_hal` crate, which gives me access to the `PhaseLockedLoopDevice<State, Device>` trait. I created an `enum` to make it easier to work with without so many generic type parameters everywhere:

```rust
enum PllState<PllDev: PhaseLockedLoopDevice> {
    Disabled(PllDev),
    Locked(PhaseLockedLoop<pll::Locked, PllDev>),
}
```

I then tried to implement the `From<>` trait so that I could call `PllState::into()` to get the inner `PllDev` that it wraps around:

```rust
impl<PllDev: PhaseLockedLoopDevice> From<PllState<PllDev>> for PllDev {
    fn from(value: PllState<PllDev>) -> Self {
        match value{
            PllState::Locked(p) => p.free(),
            PllState::Disabled(p) => p
        }
    }
}
```

This then gives me the following error:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `PllDev` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`PllState<PllDev>`)
   --> src\kernel\clocks.rs:590:6
    |
590 | impl<PllDev: PhaseLockedLoopDevice> From<PllState<PllDev>> for PllDev {
    |      ^^^^^^ type parameter `PllDev` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`PllState<PllDev>`)
    |
    = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local, and no uncovered type parameters appear before that first local type
    = note: in this case, 'before' refers to the following order: `impl<..> ForeignTrait<T1, ..., Tn> for T0`, where `T0` is the first and `Tn` is the last
```

I'm extremely confused here, because it's saying

> only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local

`PllState` is clearly a local type, it's defined two lines above. The 'uncovered' part also doesn't make too much sense, because it's not really explained, even when reading the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0210.html).

To get around this, I tried implementing `Into<>` instead (removing the `From<>` impl),

```rust
impl<PllDev: PhaseLockedLoopDevice> Into<PllDev> for PllState<PllDev> {
    fn into(self) -> PllDev {
        match self{
            PllState::Locked(p) => p.free(),
            PllState::Disabled(p) => p
        }
    }
}
```

Gives

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Into<_>` for type `PllState<_>`
   --> src\kernel\clocks.rs:598:1
    |
598 | impl<PllDev: PhaseLockedLoopDevice> Into<PllDev> for PllState<PllDev> {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
            - impl<T, U> Into<U> for T
              where U: From<T>;
```

This also doesn't make sense, since I removed the `From<PllState<PllDev>>` impl, and there are no implementation blocks on `PllState` at all.

Comment: You can't make an impl of the form `impl<T> From<_> for T` because there's already `impl<T> From<T> for T` in the standard library. You can't exclude certain types from `T` either. Generally, `From` only can implemented from one real type to another real type. Same for `Into`.

Comment: There is [this bit on uncovered types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html#uncovered-type) in the reference, `PllDev` is one and since it's before any local type that's not allowed due to the [orphan rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#orphan-rules)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following type:

```rust
enum Void {}
```

No value of this type can be created, because there is no variant! Therefore, we should be able to convert any "value" of this type to anything else, since that case can never occur.

We therefore try this implementation, which is a natural reformulation in Rust of what we said above.

```rust
impl<T> From<Void> for T {
    fn from(x: Void) -> T {
        match x {}
    }
}
```

This might look weird at first, but it's coherent from a type point of view: since there are no branches in the match, all of them typecheck!

But it doesn't work! Why? Because there is already this implementation in the standard library:

```
impl From<Void> for Void {
    fn from(x: Void) -> Void {
        x
    }
}
```

So now there is a conflicting implementation.

This (minimal) example has the same error has yours, hopefully it helps you understand it. The error message itself is pretty bad, because it tells one that a sufficient condition that Rust checks for this not to happen isn't upheld, introducing new notions in the way. This is because Rust checks for more general cases than this one. In general, Rust error messages try to be self sufficient instead, either giving a "contradiction" in your code right away, or hinting at what could go wrong, but not in this case.

I say sufficient because, in your case, it seems obvious that `PllState<T> != T`. I'm not sure if it's rejected because there are some corner cases I don't know of, or if it's just because the compiler isn't smart enough for this yet.